# HTML: Unable to link pages

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor

I have a simple webpage say, `index.html` with this kind of anchor tags appearing over and over.

```
<a href="Systems, communication and control laboratory/Amplitude Modulation and Demodulation (Real time experiment)/Amplitude Modulation and Demodulation (Real time experiment) (Introduction).html">
     Amplitude Modulation and Demodulation (Real time experiment)
</a>
<a href="Speech Signal Processing Laboratory/Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal/Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal (Aim).html">
     Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal
</a>
```

I have this directory structure.

```
+-- index.html
+-- Systems, communication and control laboratory
    +-- BPSK Modulation and Demodulation(Real time experiment)
        +-- BPSK Modulation and Demodulation(Real time experiment) (Introduction).html
+-- Speech Signal Processing Laboratory
    +-- Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal
        +-- Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal (Aim).html
```

But when I click on link, `webpage not available` error is shown.

I'll be thankful if you can give me a hint as what/where I am not obeying proper HTML syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL in the `href` attribute must be encoded as it cannot have space characters. You can replace the spaces with `%20`.

Comment: Yes, spaces were creating problems. Thanks for the solution!!

Answer (score 1):

Your URLs in your href attributes are invalid. You can't have spaces in URLs. I suggest renaming your files to be something like: `this-is-my-new-file-name.html`.

Comment: I replaced spaces with `%20` and it worked. Thanks for pointing out the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

**According to your directory structure :**

```
- index.html
+-- Systems, communication and control laboratory
    +-- BPSK Modulation and Demodulation(Real time experiment)
        +-- BPSK Modulation and Demodulation(Real time experiment) (Introduction).html
+-- Speech Signal Processing Laboratory
    +-- Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal
        +-- Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal (Aim).html
```

**This may be work :**

```
<a href="Systems, communication and control laboratory/BPSK Modulation and Demodulation(Real time experiment)/BPSK Modulation and Demodulation(Real time experiment) (Introduction).html">
     BPSK Modulation and Demodulation (Real time experiment)
</a>
<a href="Speech Signal Processing Laboratory/Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal/Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal (Aim).html">
     Non-Stationary Nature of Speech Signal
</a>
```

some servers may be confuse with spaces :)